# Conditionally rendering an element as a link to implement HAL in Java

Tags: java, json, marshalling, jackson

I'm trying to implement the [HAL standard for JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) in a JAX-RS service. My project consists of Users containing many Projects containing many Nodes containing a variety of data and pointers to other Nodes.

So when an endpoint is hit, I'd like to embed objects one level deep, and link after that:

- /user has user data and "_embedded" projects, but those projects only
  contain "_links" to nodes (and self)
- /project/1234 has "_embedded" nodes, but those nodes "_links" to further data.

And so on.

The Jackson JSONFilters look close, but I'm not quite grasping it. Especially relevant is that sometimes a property will be mapped in a collection of "_embedded" and sometimes in "_links" using different techniques.

Any one ever try something like this?

There is HalBuilder, but it seems like it requires hand serialization, which I'd like to avoid. Then again, Jackson seems to be almost as much code as hand serializing.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to implement your custom Jackson Serializer ( http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonSerializer.html )

Take a look at Spring Hateoas project. They have implemented a jackson extension `HalJacksonModule` ( https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hateoas/commit/61e73107c1213556c025dc8f68a8784daf089796
 ) to enable HAL serialization to Jackson. I think you can use it or adapt it to your needs.

Additionally, the project "Spring Data Rest" (http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest) provides a way to export your JPA model to REST (with hateoas) using Spring Hateoas. You may look at the code to get inspiration or simply use the framework in your code. (Remember to register the `HalJacksonModule` into the `ObjectMapper`).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the RestExpress library is pretty fantastic and it includes support for HAL. The author did all of the work of build the serialization mechanisms and links building based on one simple configuration.

https://github.com/RestExpress/HyperExpress

https://github.com/RestExpress/HyperExpress/tree/master/hal